# How to PXE boot if BIOS does not suppport it

Tags: boot, bios, pxe-boot

Situation: I have an old rack server that I want to use as a test machine. The BIOS does not support network boot, and cannot be upgraded. I need to install a fresh OS on it.

Is there anything I can install (or better, a live CD I can boot from), that would enable me to perform a once-only PXE-boot to load one of our standard OS images on the server?

Note: This question does NOT ask how to set up a PXE-boot server. That's already done, and works fine for any machine whose BIOS supports boot from network. All I'm looking for is a way of achieving the same thing without requiring BIOS support.

Answer (score 5):

There is this thing called gpxe (read about it [here](http://etherboot.org/wiki/index.php)), which allows you to load the PXE stuff from a floppy, for example.

Comment: What's a floppy? (jk)

Comment: Those things you keep to put coffeecups on in case you run out of CD's

Comment: "for example" == cd iso, usb stick image etc

Comment: @sajb "(jk)" == just kidding.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

http://rom-o-matic.net/ is a site where you can generate bootable images for performing pxe boot.  Another alternative is to stick another network card in the machine that does have a boot ROM.  You can just use it for network booting, and then use the other network interface for all other network activities.

BTW, there is a pretty good (geeky) Google Tech Talk about gPXE:

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1911723796712805715

Comment: +1 for noting that PXE isn't a BIOS feature at all, it's a function of the NIC.

Comment: it is a function of the NIC but often is a BIOS feature.  seems lately more often than not.

Answer (score 3):

http://ipxe.org/ will also help you in case
you have a pc that doesn't already support pxe.
There you get a bootable iso image, so if your pc 
can boot a cdrom, you can boot over pxe!

Comment: iPXE used to be called gPXE, which used to be called Etherboot. Same thing as wzzrd's answer.